# Dynamic table names and variables in sub-query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to build a query like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM code
WHERE code.id = 2 AND
EXISTS (SELECT id FROM code.src_table_name WHERE (id = code.src_table_id AND (!archived OR archived = 0)))
```

Obviously this does not work but I will explain what I want to achieve.

Example `code` table looks like the following:

```
id  |  src_table_name  |  src_table_id
1      comment            2
2      like               21
3      comment            3
```

Then the `comment` and `like` table could look like the following:

```
comment table
-------------
id  |  archived  |  comment
2      0            test
3      1            test1

like table
-------------
id
21
```

Of course these are simplified table structures.

There are two tasks that the query needs to fulfill:

```
1. Check if table mentioned in src_table_name exists
2. Check if this table has a column called `archived`.
       - If `archived` column does not exist, continue
       - If `archived` column exists, make sure it is equal to 0
```

EDIT: Some sample result data
When we have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM code
WHERE code.id = 1 AND
EXISTS (SELECT id FROM code.src_table_name WHERE (id = code.src_table_id AND (!archived OR archived = 0)))
```

This would give me:

```
id  |  src_table_name  |  src_table_id
1      comment            2
```

Because `comment` table exists (mentioned in src_table_name), row with id `2` exists (mentioned in src_table_id), `archived` column in comment table exists and `archived = 0`

Comment: What's your expect result from your sample data

Comment: @D-Shih okay let me add a few sample result data

Comment: A SQL query assumes that the tables and columns exist.  You need to do the logic checking for existence outside of the `select` -- and this suggests dynamic SQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I might have found a way to check if column exists. I will post the answer later. But I am stuck with the first part. How do I use the name of the table mentioned in `src_table_name` inside `code` table as a table for the select subquery? That is in `EXISTS (SELECT id FROM code.src_table_name WHERE ...`